# pushing from a bare repository to another bare repository

Tags: git, repository

We are looking to have a Git architecture like the following.

[image: Git architecture]

I have created two bare repositories for these.

1. //production/repo/MyProject.git (**prod-repo**)
2. //dev/repo/MyProject.git        (**dev-repo**)

After pushing my code to the **dev-repo** and testing it, I want to `push` all the changes to **prod-repo**. Obviously I won't have a working directory on either of these machines? How can I `push` all the files in the **dev-repo** to **prod-repo**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have a working copy to do push and fetch operations with git, so just push as you normally would:

```
git push prod <branch>
```

Working copies are only necessary if you're going to be modifying (or possibly modifying) code (like with a commit, merge, rebase, pull, etc).